# Where can I see all elections currently in process?

Tags: discussion, election

Is there a single place where I can see all the elections in process without checking each site individually?  Something like `stackexchange.com/elections` would be nice...

Comment: We could get CNN and Wolf Blitzer to cover it.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid comment, but if you don't notice the election system message on a site sometime during the two weeks it's running, you probably can't/shouldn't be voting in it anyway

Comment: Maybe we need to set up a Situation Room in chat.

Comment: @michael Still wouldn't be a bad idea to have a location with either the current results or the latest finished results.

Comment: @Bill http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/221/the-situation-room

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been pointed in the direction of this page: http://elections.stackexchange.com/ - elections currently in progress are the big icons.

Comment: The link returns "site not found"